# How to use 'ping' on Fedora Docker

Tags: docker

In container root `/` directory I type

```
ping
```

and get

```
bash: ping: command not found
```

then I type

```
yum install iputils
```

then I type

```
ping
```

and I get

```
bash: /usr/bin/ping: Operation not permitted
```

then I do

```
sudo ping
```

and I get

```
bash: sudo: command not found
```

so I type

```
yum install sudo
```

and I type

```
sudo ping
```

and I get

```
sudo: unable to execute /bin/ping: Operation not permitted
```

and at this point I give up and throw my hands in the air ...

so how can I use `ping` util, and I also want to use other utils like `hostname` and `ifconfig`

Comment: How do you get into the container?

Comment: Generally you don't use Docker this way; instead you [build a custom image containing your application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) and install the specific set of tools you need.  As a general rule, never install software in an interactive shell in a container: you'll lose everything as soon as the container exits.

Answer (score 6):

It works with latest fedora

```
$ docker run -it fedora /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'fedora:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/fedora
01eb078129a0: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:8ee55e140e8751492ab2cfa4513c82093cd2716df9311ea6f442f1f1259cbb3e
Status: Downloaded newer image for fedora:latest

[root@5eee4a163a0e /]# pwd
/

[root@5eee4a163a0e /]# ping
bash: ping: command not found

[root@5eee4a163a0e /]# yum install iputils
Fedora Modular 29 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                  349 kB/s | 1.5 MB     00:04
Fedora Modular 29 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                                                        291 kB/s | 2.1 MB     00:07
Fedora 29 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                                                                4.3 MB/s |  25 MB     00:05
Fedora 29 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                          5.0 MB/s |  62 MB     00:12
Dependencies resolved.
============================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                        Architecture                                  Version                                                   Repository                                     Size
============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 iputils                                        x86_64                                        20180629-2.fc29                                           fedora                                        130 k

Transaction Summary
============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 130 k
Installed size: 334 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
iputils-20180629-2.fc29.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                           84 kB/s | 130 kB     00:01
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                        45 kB/s | 130 kB     00:02
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                                                    1/1
  Installing       : iputils-20180629-2.fc29.x86_64                                                                                                                                                     1/1
  Running scriptlet: iputils-20180629-2.fc29.x86_64                                                                                                                                                     1/1
  Verifying        : iputils-20180629-2.fc29.x86_64                                                                                                                                                     1/1

Installed:
  iputils-20180629-2.fc29.x86_64

Complete!

[root@5eee4a163a0e /]# ping
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV64] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
            [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
            [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
            [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
Usage: ping -6 [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
             [-l preload] [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option]
             [-N nodeinfo_option] [-p pattern] [-Q tclass] [-s packetsize]
             [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option] [-w deadline]
             [-W timeout] destination

[root@5eee4a163a0e /]#
```

Comment: I am surprised that works. Ping requires the ability to construct ICMP packets which can wreak havoc on a network if used maliciously, so they are restricted to admin users. Your Docker setup allows containers to execute admin-level actions? Does not seem safe.

Comment: @ZanLynx no, he just opened the container as `root`. At that point the system assumes he knows what he's doing :)

Answer (score 1):

After installing **iputils*, you should set `CAP_NET_RAW` capabilities:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+p /bin/ping
```

As per [therealkenc's post](https://gitmemory.com/issue/microsoft/WSL/5109/616320311):

> mortals don't have CAP_NET_RAW by default.